# Problems with placing one canvas above another one

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

```
var origCanv=document.getElementById("canvas1");
var canv=document.createElement("CANVAS");
document.body.appendChild(canv);
canv.width=origCanv.width;
canv.height=origCanv.height;
var rect=origCanv.getBoundingClientRect();
canv.style.position="fixed";
canv.style.top=rect.top;
canv.style.left=rect.left;
canv.style.zIndex=999999;
```

If I make position absolute, the canvas is seen, but not in right place, if I make it fixed, I cant see it at all!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a unit specifier on the `top` and `left` attributes and use `position:absolute`.

```
canv.style.position = 'absolute';
canv.style.top = rect.top + 'px';
canv.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
```

Probably also want to use a sane z-index. No index is necessary if canvas1 isn't positioned. Otherwise try lowest number > canvas1.style.zIndex

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3D6T/2)